# Square of difference of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Reading this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/1150402.1150420), I am trying to follow the calculation, but I cannot understand this equation:

$$ (X - FG^T)(X^T - GF^T) = X^TX -2F^TXG + G^TGF^TF $$

where $X$, $G$, $F$ are positive matrices.

Can someone please help me with the steps to derive the right-side from the left-side?

Comment: "Positive matrices"? What do you mean? Often, one speaks of positive-definite matrices, which are symmetric, so there would be no need for transpositions.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, ( not my field, this is why I am asking silly questions).  I mean all the elements of all the three matrices are greater or equal to 0.

Comment: In general, this is false. There may be particular properties of $X, F, G$ that allow it to be true for the case in that paper.  But it is behind a paywall, so I do not know what they are. "Positive" is not at all sufficient for it.